Pine script ta.highestbars() not returning most recent occurrence but first
When I use the code below to caculate the highest high/lowest low bars ago, and there are multiple bars that match, it returns the bars back number of the first occurrence but I need to work with the most recent occurrence. Is this possible?
Here's the code with barsSinceLow and barsSinceHigh always being an integer of 1 or higher.
// Bars since recent low/high
barsSinceLow                       = math.abs(ta.lowestbars(pullbackUpBarsToCheck))                 // How many bars back is the lowest low to start the calculation of the pullback up
barsSinceHigh                      = math.abs(ta.highestbars(pullbackDownBarsToCheck))              // How many bars back is the highest high to start the calculation of the pullback down

Have plotted the output of barsSinceLow and barsSinceHigh to check the output in the Data Window for debugging, so I'm sure it returns the first occurrence (which I want to modify to most recent occurrence).

You can do this with a simple for loop. Simply loop starting from the last bar until your lookback period and only update the price and bar index if the nth bar is higher and do not check for equality.
Here is a test case I found on FXCM:EURUSD on the 1min timeframe on Oct 10, at 04:04.
The highest high at that point within the last 100 bars is 1.09428. This happens at 02:37 (87 bars since) and at 03:45 (19 bars since).
Your example code returs 87 as you explained. The for loop method returns 19 which is what you want.
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

lookback = input.int(100)

barsSinceHigh = math.abs(ta.highestbars(lookback))
highPrice = high[barsSinceHigh]

plotchar(barsSinceHigh, "barsSinceHigh", "")
plotchar(highPrice, "highPrice", "")

// ------------------------------------
hh = high
hh_bars = 0


for i = 0 to lookback - 1
    if (high[i] > hh)
        hh := high[i]
        hh_bars := i

plotchar(hh, "hh", "")
plotchar(hh_bars, "hh_bars", "")


